# Multiple indirect variables with let command (GNU/Linux Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, variables, let

```
FontName=Ubuntu
FontSize=300
let $FontName$FontSize=21
```

Getting the value is easy using the following:

```
echo $Ubuntu300
21
```

However, how can I get the same result using variables?

I tried something like:

```
echo ${!FontName!FontSize}
```

but no luck, I hope I am at least close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign your new dynamic variable to a new one, like this:

```
var=$FontName$FontSize
```

Then use indirect parameter expansion to get its value:

```
echo ${!var}
```

Will output `21`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this :

```
FontName=Ubuntu
FontSize=300
let ${FontName}${FontSize}=21

echo $Ubuntu300
21
```

For curiosity, instead of assigning new variable :

```
echo $((${FontName}${FontSize}))
21
```

Comment: jderfinko, I think you meant `echo $((${FontName}${FontSize}))`

However, that worked, and I got the expected result!

Thank you, I was also curious if it was possible to do without assigning a new variable